# How to know Python Queue in full active?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I am using code as below for multiple thread in python3, I tried Threads in cpu_count() with 2, 3 and 4 times, but I am not sure if all those threads in using, how can I check if there are some queues are never used?

```
queue = Queue()

for x in range(cpu_count() * 2):
    worker = DownloadWorker(queue)
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()

queue.join()

class DownloadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            link, download_path = self.queue.get()
            download_link(link, download_path)
            self.queue.task_done()

def downloadImage(imageServer, imageLocal, queue):
    queue.put((imageServer, imageLocal))
```

Comment: in the code example above you only have one queue that is passed to all workers.How does the DownloadWorker class look like?

Comment: I modified question.  by the way, if thread1, 3, 4 are waiting, does thread1 should be executed next?

Comment: what is `self.queue.task_done` and how is the queue filled with elements?

Comment: queue.task_done is by Queue not by mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know if all your threads are working, you can just print the thread name every time it starts a task:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import random

import time


class DownloadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.queue.get()
            print('Thread: {}'.format(self.name))
            time.sleep(random.random())

queue = Queue()
for i in range(100):
    queue.put('data')

queue.task_done()

for x in range(4):
    worker = DownloadWorker(queue)
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()

time.sleep(10)
```

Queue uses `threading.Condition` internally to block/release threads that called `get()` and `threading.Condition` uses a `threading.Lock`. From the documentation of `threading.Lock`:

> When more than one thread is blocked in acquire() waiting for the
>   state to turn to unlocked, only one thread proceeds when a release()
>   call resets the state to unlocked; which one of the waiting threads
>   proceeds is not defined, and may vary across implementations.

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: Like you said, I use code to log thread name: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s')`. I found even if threads are 4 or 6, all threads are logged, so I want to know if thread1 and thread3 are waiting, does thread1 should be executed?

Comment: Edited answer, hope this answers your question.

Comment: So which thread will be processed not only by order of thread created order?